# Сортировка в массиве

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Необходимо получить названия всех таблиц (они все в формате `DDMMYYYY`) из бд и вывести самую позднюю по такой дате.
Я не смог сделать такой запрос, поэтому стал выкручиваться через массив:

```
$choose_last=$actual_data->query ("SHOW TABLES");

            }; 

            while ($tbl=$choose_last->fetch_row()){
                   $tbl_array[]=($tbl); 

            }
```

Тут явно ошибка, потому что очень странно нумеруются индексы.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 00000000 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 01102018 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 05102018 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 09102018 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 15102018 ))
```

Почему выводится столько значений `Array`?
Можно ли будет потом значения массива отсортировать по дате?
Какая должна быть функция?

Comment: Потому что каждый `$tbl` это массив полей. Функции сортировки массивов описаны [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/array.sorting.php)

Comment: Что я должен изменить чтобы получить индекс-значение?

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку

Comment: Какое значение вы хотите получить?

Comment: Я ожидал что получу автонумерованный индекс и его значение, которое возьмется из запроса fetch_row

Comment: __Почаще__ читайте мануалы http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Comment: Я конечно пытаюсь это читать, но для начинающего порой не ясно как это применить. Этот сайт похож на справочник для человека, который все-таки понимает как это все работает. Спасибо вам.