# Нужен код для перевода mysqli_result Object в нумерованный массив

Tags: php, массивы

Необходимо получить названия всех таблиц (они все в формате `DDMMYYYY`) из бд и вывести самую позднюю по такой дате. Я не смог сделать такой запрос, поэтому стал выкручиваться через массив

```
 $choose_last=$actual_data->query ("SHOW TABLES"); 
 print_r ($choose_last);
```

Я получил результат:

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 7 [type] => 0 )
```

Я понимаю что `[num_rows] => 7` это мои 7 таблиц в БД. 
Как теперь мне преобразовать этот `mysqli_result Object` в обычный массив с цифровыми индексами? Мне нужно чтобы полученные названия таблиц оказались в таком массиве. Вида `$array[0]=Название 1 таблицы, $array[1]=Название 2` таблицы итд. 
Благодарю за любую помощь!

Comment: Вот у вас же вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/895707/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5 Что мешает его докрутить?

Comment: Ну то что вы посоветовали читать мануалы вместо конкретного ответа. Я пытаюсь разобраться, делю задачу на фрагменты, спрашиваю. А мне один известный совет. Мне на английском стаковерфлоу человек спокойно ответил и без пренебрежения к новичкам.

Comment: В мануале написано что `fetch_row` возвращает массив. Если вам нужен конкретный элемент массива - то используйте `[]` нотацию. В итоге вы можете написать `$tbl_array[]=$tbl[0];` и получить что надо. И всё. Что здесь __сложного__?

Comment: Вот вы пишете золотые слова "Если вам нужен конкретный элемент массива - то используйте [] нотацию". На http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php такого пояснения нет. Спасибо вам, я буду пробовать.

Comment: О чем пояснения? Серьезно, вам надо в каждой функции что возвращает массив писать "чтобы получить конкретный элемент используйте `[]`"?

Comment: Друг, я этому учусь, поэтому не все сразу понимаю. Извините пожалуйста. Для этого и пришел на форум. Или тут только профи?

Comment: @u_mulder Спасибо вам. Все получилось сделать. Массив теперь нормальный. Теперь мне его нужно будет сортировать по дате как-то. Но буду мануал читать. Если не получится - буду писать, уж извините.

Answer (score 0):

Автор, teran прав. Для примера, могу вам подкинуть только идею, а выкрутите как хотите:

Судя по всему, запрос нужно сделать такой:

```
select * from information_schema.tables
```

Ответ, примерно такой:

```
$mysql= new mysqli .......
$a = $mysql->query()->fetch_all();
```

Comment: Я пробовал этот запрос select * from information_schema.tables, но он выводит названия не только из моей БД! Если я ставил параметр ASC запрос возвращал 00000000 (мою таблицу), а вслучае с DESC таблицу Views из БД information_schema.

Comment: @musorgsky Тогда вот такой: SHOW TABLES FROM <databaseName>

Comment: Скажите а зачем указывать SHOW TABLES FROM <databaseName> если я в подключении уже подключился к <databaseName>?

Comment: Переведите дословно синтаксис, потом спомните свой вопрос, запустите в среде этот пример

Comment: Я запустил в phpMyadmin - никакой разницы нет. Что указывать FROM, что не указывать.